# Hazelcast IAtomicReference on only some nodes in the cluster

Tags: hazelcast

I have a IAtomicReference in a Hazelcast cluster.

```
IAtomicReference<Monitor> ref = ...
```

When I update the value using `alterAndGet` an `IFunction<Monitor, Monitor>` is passed to the distributed atomic reference.

The provided function may execute on any Hazelcast node in the cluster, but I'd like to make sure it executes on only some of the nodes (nodes 1, 2, 3, or 4 out of 8 total nodes).

My understanding is that Hazelcast may choose to store the IAtomicReference on any node and this is the node that will execute the provided altering function. So I guess what I need is to specify that the IAtomicReference may only be stored on some nodes.

Maybe it's worth saying that the other nodes (5, 6, 7 and 8) don't need to access the IAtomicReference at all.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control that perfectly if you rely on the partition since the partition can move around. So at some point it might be at member 1, but a moment later it might be at member 2.

If you really want to control where a task is going to run; you could have a look at the IExecutorService.submit(task, somemember)

Comment: Another option is start some members as "Lite Members" - it's a new feature in Hazelcast 3.6. Lite Member do not own any data. However this is all or nothing situation.

Comment: I don't understand, is an IAtomicReference partitioned? Also it's not that I want to run the code on a specific node, I just don't want it to be run on a range of nodes. Can I somehow specify that the given IAtomicReference may only be on a range of nodes?

Comment: @Jaromir Hamala Unfortunately I can't use lite members because I have other types of data (mostly maps) that I need to have on those other nodes...

Comment: It isn't partitioned; but it is assigned to a partition based on its name. So when the partition moved around, the IAtomicLong moves around. If you want to execute a task on a particular member; please have a look at the IExecutorService; it has methods where you can pick the member

Comment: The thing is each `IAtomicReference` belongs to a partition. In theory you could use the data-affinity feature to pin-point your reference to a partition which does belong to a member you want. 
However there might be re-partitioning when a new member joins or leaves the cluster -> the partition holding your reference might be migrated.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's like the IAtomicReferences are values in map where the key is the name I use for them when I retrieve them from the HazelcastInstance. Because of that it can be on any node, just like the values in the map can be. That makes sense. Thanks!